# Finding whether a point lies on the boundary of an geometrical object or not?

Tags: computational-geometry, image-processing, python, c++, polygons

Suppose I have the mesh of an geometrical object (Interval in 1d, Region in 2d, Volume in 3d). How can I find out whether a point lies on its boundary or not?

I am looking for algorithms with explanations. Any resource would **also** be appreciated.

Comment: A mesh for a 3D object?  Does it work to iterate over the faces/cells in the mesh, and for each face, test if the point lies (approximately) within the face?  If not, can you [edit] your question to explain what you've considered and why you've rejected them?

Comment: @D.W. I am talking about meshes in general. I want to know the algorithm for 1d, 2d, and 3d.

Comment: OK.  Does the approach I list meet your needs?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: @D.W. Do you suggest particular mesh libraries for python/C++? In your approach you mentioned the point must lie "approximately" on face. That's not exact.

Comment: Software implementations and software recommendations are typically off-topic here.  If your concern is about "approximately", I suggest editing your question to explain what approach you've considered and what your concerns are.  Help us avoid telling you something you already know, and provide background to help people provide more useful answers.

Comment: Can you describe your meshes in more details (geometry, topology) ?

Answer (score 1):

### Interval

Interval defined as $[l, r]$, test point $v$. Compute $|l-v|$ and $|r-v|$ to find distance from boundary. If the smallest of those distances is less than your tolerance, it's on the boundary.

### Region

With region defined as a list of 2d points with say $x_i, y_i$, as the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the $i^{th}$ point, and a test point $v_x, v_y$. Compute the '[point segment distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849211/shortest-distance-between-a-point-and-a-line-segment)' with every segment and compare with your tolerance. That is, the euclidean distance from each endpoint (use Pythagoras: $\sqrt{(x_i - v_x)^2 + (y_i - v_y)^2}$, and the point line distance: $\frac{|(x_{i+1}-x_i)(y_i - v_y) - (x_i - v_x)(y_{i+1}-y_i)|}{\sqrt{(x_{i+1} - x_i)^2 + (y_{i+1} - y_i)^2}}$

### Volume

I imagine that your volume is defined as a list of 3-tuples of 3d points which correspond to 3d triangles. Compute the '[point triangle distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924795/fastest-way-to-compute-point-to-triangle-distance-in-3d)' with every triangle and compare with your tolerance. Details are at the link but the usual way is to project the point onto the plane defined by the triangle and use barycentric coordinates.

#### Notes

- You may want to consider an 'acceleration structure' to avoid having to look at every segment of a region, or every triangle within the volume. Something like a kd-tree or an r-tree may be appropriate.
- For 2d and 3d cases you *must* use an appropriate tolerance as numerical precision can prevent points being exactly on your segment / triangle.
- Anything better than just checking each segment / each triangle will require doing some work up front - you will need to supply more information in your question if this is desired.
- Essentially any 3d library you use should have a method for this (CGAL, etc.)
- The more general case of 'is my point inside this volume' is trivial for interval, look up winding number for region, and look at ray tracing counting the number of intersections for a closed volume (not practically very easy in 3D!)